# I am trying to output the second half of a multidimensional array when the user inputs the first half that corresponds

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
using System;
namespace MyNameSpace
{
class DeliveryCharges
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Declare variables
        double[ , ] dblZipArray = {{40214, 5.00}, {40245, 4.85}, {40248, 2.67}, {40272, 3.79}, {40299, 5.40}, {42103, 2.30}, {42133, 4.60}, {42141, 1.00}, {42160, 1.45}, {42303, 3.60}};
        double dblUserZIP;
        int x;


        Console.Clear();

        //Ask user for zip code
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a ZIP code to view the delivery charge for that area.");
        dblUserZIP = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        x = Array.BinarySearch(dblZipArray, dblUserZIP);
        if(x < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ZIP Code {0} is not in our delivery area.", dblUserZIP);
        }
        else    
        {   
            Console.WriteLine("The price of delivery to ZIP code {0} is ${1}", dblUserZIP, dblZipArray[dblUserZIP]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

When a user inputs "42141" for example, the correct output should say: "The price of delivery to ZIP code 42141 is $1.00" When this code is compiled I am getting errors. I can't remember how to properly reference a multidimensional array. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it isn't compiling, because you must use [x,y] to access a single value from a multidimentional array. For example, dblZipArray[0,0] would return 40214, and dblZipArray[0,1] would return 5.00.

Second, you can't use Array.BinarySearch on a multidimensional array. There are no built in methods to search a binary array this way, so you'll have to write your own search function.

Here's some sample code that works, though it could error checking on the user's input, could likely use a more effective search (especially if you know your zip code list is sorted), and also, consider that your double array could be rewritten as a struct or class with int ZipCode and double Price, since Zip being a double wastes space, and this makes functions like .length operate a little more logically for your use case (with a multidimentional array, it returns the total number of cells in the array, whereas you would likely want it to return the number of zip codes you support).

Edit: as brz pointed out below, a dictionary would be even better for this.

```
static void Main()
    {
        //Declare variables
        double[,] dblZipArray = { { 40214, 5.00 }, { 40245, 4.85 }, { 40248, 2.67 }, { 40272, 3.79 }, { 40299, 5.40 }, { 42103, 2.30 }, { 42133, 4.60 }, { 42141, 1.00 }, { 42160, 1.45 }, { 42303, 3.60 } };
        double dblUserZIP;

        Console.Clear();

        //Ask user for zip code
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a ZIP code to view the delivery charge for that area.");
        dblUserZIP = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        int zip;

        for (zip = 0; zip < dblZipArray.Length / 2; zip++ )
        {
            if (dblZipArray[zip,0] == dblUserZIP)
            {
                break;
            }
        }



            if (zip == dblZipArray.Length /2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ZIP Code {0} is not in our delivery area.", dblUserZIP);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The price of delivery to ZIP code {0} is ${1}", dblUserZIP, dblZipArray[zip, 1]);
            }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong data structure:

1. You only want a key-value lookup table and you'll have a **single** double value corresponding to a key, not a set of values.
2. You don't want duplicate keys in your data structure.

You have to use a Dictionary instead:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //Declare variables
        Dictionary<int, double> zipDic = new Dictionary<int, double> { { 40214, 5.00 }, { 40245, 4.85 }, { 40248, 2.67 }, { 40272, 3.79 }, { 40299, 5.40 }, { 42103, 2.30 }, { 42133, 4.60 }, { 42141, 1.00 }, { 42160, 1.45 }, { 42303, 3.60 } };

        Console.Clear();

        //Ask user for zip code
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a ZIP code to view the delivery charge for that area.");
        var zipCode = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (!zipDic.ContainsKey(zipCode))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ZIP Code {0} is not in our delivery area.", zipCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The price of delivery to ZIP code {0} is ${1}", zipCode, zipDic[zipCode]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```